# How to click on an element and use javascripts "copy" event to add to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, clipboard

Javascript finally has the "copy" event and we no longer have to use flash! (well, we still should use flash as a fallback).

[http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/#x3.1.1-copy-event](http://jsfiddle.net/LkUhM/)

I'm trying to figure out how to: Click on an anchor tag (Copy) and it copies the (text input src /or innerHTML) to the clipboard. Here's a fiddle of the HTML/CSS http://jsfiddle.net/LkUhM/

Can anyone guide me?

:::::HTML:::::

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" class="input" value="This is the next that will be copied!" /><a href="#" id="copy" class="copy">Copy!</a></li>
    <li><input type="text" class="input" value="This is the next that will be copied!" /><a href="#" id="copy" class="copy">Copy!</a></li>
    <li><input type="text" class="input" value="This is the next that will be copied!" /><a href="#" id="copy" class="copy">Copy!</a></li>
    <li><input type="text" class="input" value="This is the next that will be copied!" /><a href="#" id="copy" class="copy">Copy!</a></li>
</ul>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: well.. maybe it was just wishful thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're looking at an old version of that spec.  The new one is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/
2. According to the current spec, you **cannot** programmatically simulate any of these clipboard events. I am trying to work with the appropriate W3C working group to get that changed to at least allow simulation when the user clicks and/or issues a keyboard event (just like how you can get write access to the clipboard with Flash).

Comment: Thankyou. I was in the process of creating a html5 web app (for mobile), and was planning on using the "flash copy/paste" hack...but to my dismay I came to realize that flash in NOT installed on phones..or at least androids. So I've been trying to find a solution ever since and hoping that some form of js solution would be created.

Comment: **Android:** You _can_ install Flash on Android (for now) but Adobe already announced that it will not be supported anymore.

**Blackberry 10:** Flash comes stock on Blackberry 10 OS phones but it is also disabled by default, so you have to go into the browser settings to enable it; I would _guess_ it won't be supported for much longer, though.

**iOS:** You cannot install Flash on iOS (iPhones, iPads, etc.).

**Windows Phone:** You cannot install Flash on Windows Phone (WP7, etc.).